# Minimize a quadratic equation with diagonalization

Tags: diagonalization

I have a problem to solve and I have no idea how to do.
I need to find the maximum and minimum of $G=2x²+2y²-15z²+8xy-12yz-12xz$ with $x²+y²+z²=1$
I'm supposed to use the diagonalization but I don't know with which matrix started... Thanks for your help :)

Comment: You need to find the points (x,y,z) such that the partial derivatives are all equal to zero. Also when $x^2+y^2+z^2=1$ then how can  $G$ be written?

Comment: I can write G just in term of x and y ?

Comment: Not quite, but it would be easier to compute the derivatives this way: $G=2(x^2+y^2+z^2)-17z^2+8xy-12yz-12xz$. So now you find the points : $f_x=0,f_y=0,f_z=0$ After that I'm assuming you'll need the Hessian.

Comment: Thanks, but is it normal that I find x=y=z=0 when I compute the partital derivative ?

Answer (score 0):

**hint**: Lagrange Multiplier will work for this question ! Let $H(x,y,z) = x^2+y^2+z^2-1$, and solve $\nabla G = \alpha \nabla H$. You solve for $x,y,z, \alpha$.

Comment: I know I can do it with Lagrange multiplier but is it possible to solve it with matrix diagonalization ?

Answer (score 0):

Hint: You can write G = $x' \cdot Q \cdot x$ where $x = \begin{bmatrix}
    x \\
    y \\
    z
\end{bmatrix}$ and $Q = \begin{bmatrix}
    2 & 4 & -6  \\
    4 & 2 & -6 \\
    -6 & -6 & -15
\end{bmatrix} $

Comment: Thanks, now I found a diagonal matrix : J = [ -18 0 0, 0 -2 0, 0 0 9] How can I deduce the maximum and the minimum now ?

Comment: And how can i use the condition x² +y²+z²=1 ?

Comment: The minimum would be -18, and the maximum 9. With the solutions being the normalized eigenvectors corresponding to those eigenvalues.

Comment: Thanks a lot, and now, how can i find the coordinates of the maximum and the minimum ?

Comment: Because after finding the value of the maximum and the minimum, I have to find the values of 3x²+2y²+z² when G is maximum and minimum

Comment: So for example the minimum eigenvalue -18, corresponded with the eigenvector $\begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 1 & 4
\end{bmatrix}$, when normalized it becomes $\begin{bmatrix}
    \frac{1}{3 \sqrt{2}} & \frac{1}{3 \sqrt{2}}  & \frac{4}{3 \sqrt{2}} 
\end{bmatrix}$

Comment: @MathieuHassenforder: note that $1=x^T x=x^T R^{-1} R x = x^T R^T R x=(Rx)^T (Rx)$, where $Q=R^{-1} D R= R^T D R$.

Comment: Oh yeah !! I solved the problem ! Thanks a lot for your help :)

Comment: @MathieuHassenforder if this answered your question, you can accept this answer.